# CentOS server - intranet- domain name without local dns

Tags: centos, web-server, intranet

I am running a CentOS PXE/webserver and would like to use a domain name such as fresh.srv instead of typing in the IP address to access the website on a client computer.  Is this possible with out running a local DNS server?  Thank you!

Comment: Why do you not want a local DNS server? DNS is generally The Right Way to handle this...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the `hosts` file.

Edit `/etc/hosts`on the client, and add a line like:

```
192.168.10.10 fresh.srv
```

...of course replacing that IP address with the IP of your server.