# Git Remote Server Configuration

Tags: centos, php, git, repository

I am building an intranet for development purposes for my development team. So far I have a new CentOS box with Git installed, and a repository initialized. My goal is for developers to access the repository by connecting through the network. There are not any domains hosted on the box since we really have not started using it for that purpose yet.

Soo.... I want developers to git remote to the repository but I am stumbling trying to figure out how I would set that up. Should I use the network address such as 192.168.2.XX? Does it absolutely have to be bound to a domain? I will also admit I am not a Linux expert and do not know what to do about setting it up.

Perhaps maybe I could do this if I have to, but I would also have to mess with DNS in the network (which I don't have access to): 
[CentOS server - intranet- domain name without local dns](https://serverfault.com/questions/536345/centos-server-intranet-domain-name-without-local-dns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into it extensively, I have decided the best way to make this work would have to be setting up access to the drive on the network using Samba.

I have exposed the drives on the network to make them accessible, and a command line user can simply navigate to it. Also, the 'git remote add' command **does not require a web address**. Therefore, you **can specify a drive** path which solves my problem.

I suppose the path would have worked if I specified a network address, such as 196.168.2.XX... However, neither direction was easy and led me down several rabbit holes (at least because I'm a novice Linux guy).

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason to have a domain name to connect to a git repository, you can just use the internal IP.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) too for an easy way to manage git repositories.